# Where is Apple Service ID( Client ID) for Azure B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

Does anyone know where to get the Apple service ID ( client ID) to set up Identity Provider of Apple in Azure B2C?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you [Create an Apple ID application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-apple-id?pivots=b2c-user-flow#create-an-apple-id-application), you should be able to get the **Identifier** from the step 8.

> b. Enter the Identifier, such as `com.consoto.azure-ad-b2c-service`. The
> identifier is your client ID for the OpenID Connect flow.

Please check it.